# What is the difference between Machine and Time Cycle in 8085 microprocessor?

Tags: microprocessor

I have search this topic but their I can not find any specific answer to this . So I need some specific answers .

Comment: Can you share with us the result of your research?

Comment: Also, where did you get the phrase "Machine and Time Cycle"? That isn;t how I would express things.

Comment: What does the question mean?

Comment: @copper.hat If you understand microprocessors you understand what the question means. It's perfectly clear to me what the question is.

Comment: @gbulmer The phrases are perfectly common terms for microprocessors.  Time cycles (also known as \$T_{CY}\$) and Machine cycles (\$M_{CY}\$).

Comment: @copper.hat Clock cycle, time cycle (\$T_{CY}\$), frequency cycle (\$F_{CY}\$) and "clock period" are all synonyms for the same thing. It often depends on the manufacturer which is used.

Comment: @copper.hat By knowing how a CPU operates you know it has 3 basic cycle levels - instruction, machine, and clock or time. The trick then is fitting the terms in the question into that model, and they fit perfectly.

Comment: @Majenko - I live and learn. I started using microprocessors in the 70's, now use MCU's, and track processor designs. I have never read 'Time Cycle'. I do of course recognise clock cycle, clock period, machine cycle, instruction cycle, instruction period, etc. but not 'Time cycle'. I am very curious which manufacturer uses 'frequencycycle'? Are they Microchip terms?

Comment: I would second @gbulmer's comments.

Comment: I've never heard of a time cycle. Clock cycle is commonly used.

Comment: Just to be accurate, I found an old [8085 datasheet](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~calazans/undergrad/orgcomp_EC/mat_microproc/intel-8085_datasheet.pdf). I think it might be truncated, and it is only a scan, so no text search. It uses Tcyc, and calls that "Clock Cycle period", which I recognise, and expect. AFAICT, it does *not* mention Time Cycle. So I think answering my question "where did you get the phrase 'Machine and Time Cycle'?" is still useful.

Comment: What do you think the "T" in "Tcyc" stands for? It certainly doesn't stand for Clock, now, does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A time cycle is one tick of the core CPU clock.  A machine cycle is what the internal state machine of the CPU is doing at the time.

[This document explains it all in detail](http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/000495.pdf)

Basically the machine cycles are:

- Opcode Fetch (OF)
- Memory Read
- Memory Write
- I/O Read (I/OR)
- I/O Write (I/OW)
- Acknowledge of INTR (INTA)
- BUS Idle (BI) : DAD
- ACK of RST, TRAP
- HALT
- HOLD

The first one, Opcode Fetch, is described as:

> Each read or writes operation
>   constitutes a machine cycle. The instructions of 8085 require 1–5 machine cycles containing
>   3–6 states (clocks). The 1st machine cycle of any instruction is always an Op. Code fetch cycle
>   in which the processor decides the nature of instruction. It is of at least 4-states. It may go up
>   to 6-states.

... continued later ...

> The process of opcode fetch operation requires minimum 4-clock cycles \$T_1\$, \$T_2\$, \$T_3\$ and \$T_4\$ and is the 1st machine cycle (M 1 ) of every instruction.

... and another good snippet that describes the relationship more ...

> It is well known that an instruction cycle consists of many machine cycles. Each machine
>   cycle consists of many clock periods or cycles, called T-states. The 1st machine cycle (\$M_1\$) of
>   every instruction cycle is the opcode fetch cycle. In the opcode fetch cycle, the processor comes
>   to know the nature of the instruction to be executed. The processor during (\$M_1\$ cycle) puts the
>   program counter contents on the address bus and reads the opcode of the instruction through read
>   process. The \$T_1\$, \$T_2\$ , and \$T_3\$ clock cycles are used for the basic memory read operation and the
>   \$T_4\$ clock and beyond are used for its interpretation of the opcode. Based on these interpretations,
>   the μP comes to know the type of additional information/data needed for the execution of the
>   instruction and accordingly proceeds further for 1 or 2-machine cycle of memory read and writes.

So that machine cycle takes 4 (minimum) time cycles.

Comment: The document http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/000495.pdf doesn't seem "explains it all in detail". It does not use the term "Time Cycle".

Comment: Time == Clock.  A "Time Cycle" is a "Clock Cycle" - they are one and the same thing. [...]

Comment: Others do not recognising the term either, so IMHO it would be useful to have the OP provide the source for the question's terms, and remove assumptions. Or have the question edited to correct the terms.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this old question; since it's something I've looked into in detail I might as well answer despite its age.

Dividing processor execution into machine cycles (M cycles) and time states (T states) goes way back to the Intel 8008 ([datasheet](http://www.classiccmp.org/8008/8008UM.pdf)). The idea is that one machine cycle corresponds to one memory access. Each memory access required multiple clock cycles, each one corresponding to a T state. E.g. during T1 and T2 the address is sent to memory. The byte is fetched from memory in T3 and the instruction is executed in T4 and T5. The external memory monitors the T states so it knows what to do each clock period. (The state information is so important it used 3 of the 8008's 18 pins.)

Some instructions perform multiple memory accesses (e.g. fetch instruction, read data), so they have multiple machine cycles. Some machine cycles don't use all the T states or have additional T states (e.g. waiting for memory or handling an interrupt.) A machine cycle can also correspond to something other than memory access, e.g. I/O access.

To summarize: an instruction has multiple M cycles. Each M cycle consists of multiple T states, each corresponding to one clock cycle.

This structure of M cycles and T states persisted into the 8008's descendants: 8080, 8085 and Z-80. When x86 introduced instruction prefetching, M cycles became less relevant, although T states persisted for a while.

I've reverse-engineered the Z-80, and the chip's internal implementation is totally designed around the M cycles and T states. Instructions can have complex sequences of M cycles and T states of varying lengths. Ring counters keep track of the current M cycle and T state. The M cycle and T state signals are fed into complex gates to generate the internal control signals at the right time.

Other processors can use totally different models. For instance, the 6502 uses internal states [T0 through T6](http://www.pagetable.com/?p=39) but doesn't have the M cycle idea.